# How to create an interval in a matrix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, mdx, ssrs-grouping

I am working with SSRS 2008, my source is a cube and I use this MDX query:

```
 SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Val] } ON COLUMNS,
  NON EMPTY { ([DimCl].[Cl].[Cl].ALLMEMBERS,  
              [DDate].[Year].[Year].ALLMEMBERS ) } 
  ON ROWS FROM [DW]
```

I created a matrix with the following data

```
        2014         2015
0        10           11
1        15           10
2        15           11
3        18           14 
4        10            8
5         5            5
6        12           10
7        10           15    
8        20           18
```

I need to do an interval the result matrix should be like this:

```
2014         2015
<=2      40           32
]2;4]    28           22
]4;6]    17           15
>6       30           33
```

I tried the switch statement in SSRS but I got an error, can someone please tell me how I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by creating a group in your tablix, and using the group by expression to define your ranges. Right click on your details row in the tablix and select Add Group -> Parent Group. Click the function button next to the Group By: box. You would add something like this as your expression:

```
=iif(Fields!Val.Value <= 2, "<=2", iif(Fields!Val.Value <=4, "]2;4]", iif(Fields!Val.Value <=6, "]4;6]", ">6")))
```

Now in your new group's row in the tablix you just need to add a sum function for your values. You will get the sum for each group.

Answer (score 1):

Since you group the data and do aggregation based this "interval", I suggest you add a Calculated filed and use Switch() function in the value.

=Switch(

Fields!Val.Value <= 2, "<=2",

Fields!Val.Value <= 4, "2-4",

Fields!Val.Value <= 6, "4-6",

Fields!Val.Value >6 , ">6"
)

Then you can just group on this field and specify group name as scope in sum() function

Comment: Hi thanks for answer can you explain me more that :specify group name as scope in sum() Thanks